# Host key verification failed when using rsync in kubernetes pod

Tags: ssh, kubernetes

when I tried to use this command to copy some files from  remote machine to kuberetes pod using rsync:

```
sshpass -p "password" rsync root@172.29.217.209:/root/a.dmg /app/a.dmg
```

the commmand output like this:

```
~ # sshpass -p "password" rsync root@172.29.217.209:/root/a.dmg /app/a.dmg
Host key verification failed.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(713) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

the kubernetes pod was newly created(no cached ssh config), why still shows this error? The pod was based on alpine linux, the remote server was CentOS 7.8. this is the ssh version:

```
~ # ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
```

Comment: "Host key verification failed." <--- so, look into what SSH tells you about the host key?

Comment: seem I have to run the ssh command first to generate the `known_hosts` file.

Comment: you don't, because that file would be automatically created (usually, unless you explicitly say it should not), but you might see what is wrong.